# Tiktok like scrolling for sections

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I have recipes(sections) displayed on my page like this: **

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .recipe {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border: hidden;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
  }
  section h2 {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
  }
  section h5 {
    font-size: 1.35rem;
  }
  #container {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  input[type=text] {
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
  html {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  }
  .recipe {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/homepage.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300;400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
  <title>MyCookBook</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>MyCookBook</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
      <!--   <button type="submit"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">account_circle</span></button> -->
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="container">
    <section class="recipe">
      <h2 class="recipe_elmnt">Commodo</h2>
      <h5 class="recipe_elmnt">dignissim</h5>
      <img src="../resources/placeholder_img.jpg" alt="recipe outcome photo" class="recipe_elmnt">
      <div class="ingredients">
        <h3>Ingredients</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>eget duis at</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>eget duis at</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>eget duis at</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="procedure">
        <h3>Procedure</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="recipe">
      <h2 class="recipe_elmnt">Commodo</h2>
      <h5 class="recipe_elmnt">dignissim</h5>
      <img src="../resources/placeholder_img.jpg" alt="recipe outcome photo" class="recipe_elmnt">
      <div class="ingredients">
        <h3>Ingredients</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>eget duis at</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>eget duis at</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>eget duis at</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="procedure">
        <h3>Procedure</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="recipe">
      <h2 class="recipe_elmnt">Commodo</h2>
      <h5 class="recipe_elmnt">dignissim</h5>
      <img src="../resources/placeholder_img.jpg" alt="recipe outcome photo" class="recipe_elmnt">
      <div class="ingredients">
        <h3>Ingredients</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>eget duis at</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>eget duis at</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>eget duis at</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="procedure">
        <h3>Procedure</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to make the section(.recipe) scroll like on **TikTok**, where you can only see one video on the screen, and when you scroll you see the next one, etc. etc. when the viewport is smaller than 500px(or on a mobile device). I have tried the page-snap-* css property but for some reason, it didn't work. Could anyone help?

Comment: I've used [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for something similiar before, and I think the library works great.

Comment: your code doesn't seem to reproduce the issue. for start i would try to make each `<section>` to be full page (maybe `height: 100vh`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This codepen](https://codepen.io/joealva1957/pen/vPrKEP) might have all the answers you are looking for. For your use case, I believe the important parts are that the container of your recipes has:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh; /* Or whatever size fits your layout */
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
```

And each recipe section inside that container has:

```css
.section {
    height: 100vh; /* Or whatever size the container has */
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```